# How can I disable git cherry-pick from applying the diff of one file to another?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

The steps to reproduce my case,

```
git init foo
cd foo

# add initial a.txt on "master"
echo hello > a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -mbase

# create branch "new"
git branch new

# on "master", rename a.txt to b.txt
git mv a.txt b.txt
git commit -m'rename a.txt to b.txt'

# on "master", modify b.txt
echo world >> b.txt
git commit -am'world b'

# on "new" rename a.txt to c.txt
git switch new
git mv a.txt c.txt
git commit -m'rename a.txt to c.txt'   # Anchor 1

# apply the commit in which b.txt is modified
git cherry-pick master
```

As on branch `new`, `b.txt` does not exist and it has only `c.txt`, I expected `git cherry-pick` to fail due to conflicts. However, it succeeded and applied the diff of `b.txt` to `c.txt`.

I guess it's related to the fact that `b.txt` and `c.txt` are considered as being copied from the same origin `a.txt`, and maybe also some git merge strategy. I had a try to solve the issue,

```
# remove foo, run the commands again, and pause at # Anchor 1

# introduce b.txt from "master" to "new"
git checkout master -- b.txt
git commit -m'add b.txt from master'

# apply the commit in which b.txt is modified
git cherry-pick master
```

This way, it complains `nothing to commit, working tree clean` as expected. But, in one of my projects the situation is very common, and I cannot abandon `git cherry-pick` in the workflow. As the creation and renaming are not under my control, I cannot ask other team members to always apply all new files to other branches where they are not necessary at all.

Is there any solution to disable `git cherry-pick` from applying the diff of one file to another without any bad side effect? Thanks.

I tried git 2.19.2, 2.24.1 and 2.39.0 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ‘resolve’ merge strategy…

> […] does not handle renames.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-resolve

Use `--strategy` to choose ‘resolve’.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---strategyltstrategygt

Continuing from anchor 1 as an example:

```bash
$ git cherry-pick --strategy=resolve master
Trying simple merge.
Simple merge failed, trying Automatic merge.
ERROR: b.txt: Not handling case … ->  -> …
fatal: merge program failed
error: could not apply …... world b

$ git status
On branch new
You are currently cherry-picking commit ….

Unmerged paths:
    deleted by us:   b.txt

no changes added to commit
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a try and see if it has unexpected side effects.

Comment: The default strategy now is `ort`, a replacement of `recursive`. After some tests, I'll take `--strategy=recursive -X no-renames`. Thank you for the guidance!